# How to get Windows to identify my custom USB Security Token as a USB token instead of COM serial device

Tags: windows, usb, driver, smartcard, hsm

I have a custom **HSM**: a USB **Token**/Dongle. When I insert it in the USB port, PnP Services load it as a **COM** serial device (in the device manager). I am able to communicate with it using a custom **PKCS11** library that we are developing. BUT, I want to make it accessible to **MS CryptoAPI** users. To achieve this, I need Windows' SmartCard Services (SCardSvr) to identify it. And to do that, Windows needs to acknowledge that it is a USB Token Device instead of a COM Serial Device.
(If my logic so far is wrong, please do tell).
**My question is**: Do I have to write a completely new driver, or can I do something else to change the way Windows recognizes my device?

Comment: Forgot to say, Im using MSVS-2015 + Windows 10 (SDK + WDK)

Comment: That's entirely up to the driver for the USB device, not Windows.  Contact the vendor or manufacturer for advice.

Comment: The driver is a generic COM, Windows detects/load/installs it automatically, I want to know if I can create a "parser" or something that allows windows to view it as a USB-Token

Comment: Some misunderstanding: the PKCS11 is a driver, which knows, what commands have to be sent to the card for a given functionality like signature creation. MS Crypto API also achieves the same functionality, but by itself. No simple *configuration* provides the necessary card knowledge to WIndows.  So you have no choice but to contact the vendor.

Comment: That would be great, except there is no vendor, the processing chips were obtained from Amtel and assembled by our engineer team. Amtel provides a COM .cat/.inf driver that registers our device as COM serial, but I need Windows to see it as USB Token. This is my predicament. HELP

Comment: need think write driver - FDO for your hardwareID ( like `USB\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx`) which create PDO with `SmartCardReader` as compatible ID. but this can be enough big task

Comment: and need call `IoRegisterDeviceInterface(SmartCardReaderGuid)` and handle specific card reader requests, with Smclib.sys

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/smartcard/index

Comment: So i treat the USB-ICC like a card reader? sure about that?